# Does torrenting slow down internet browsing?

Tags: bittorrent, browsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do torrents slow down my internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/247711/why-do-torrents-slow-down-my-internet)

I was wondering if having bittorrent running would slow down my web browsing in any way?

Usually at any one time I'm downloading 20 videos/ebooks and seeding about 20 others so I get a bit worried if it will actually take a lot of resources, and begin to slow down my regular browsing.

Comment: It depends on the specific settings and number of active torrents. In addition to sucking bandwidth, “torrenting” can also suck CPU cycles and slow down a system in that way as well, especially for browsing Flash/JavaScript-heavy sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, most bittorrent clients will use as much of the available bandwidth as they can get. So, yes, it can definitely slow down your internet.  Most of the time you won't notice it for normal web surfing: reading e-mail, reading news, or facebook. But if you're playing games or watching videos online, it will definitely have an impact — possibly a severe impact.  If you're sharing a connection with anyone, bittorrent is just plain anti-social.

Fortunately, most bittorrent clients allow you to set up limits.  How you do this or what you need to set up depends on the client, and they are rarely limited correctly when you first install them.

Unless you're really serious about your downloads, my personal recommendation is to limit bittorrent to less than 20 percent of your total *actual* download throughput, and less than 10 percent of your total *actual* upload throughput.  To find those numbers, you'll need to do a series of speed tests to see what your actual values are.  Don't just do the test once: re-test multiple times at multiple times a day over a period of a couple weeks.  Use the *lowest* numbers recorded and limit your bittorrent to 10% of that.

Of course, if you're more serious about your downloads this won't work for you.  But if you view it as more of a background process, this works well.

Answer (score 3):

It *can* especially be a problem on DSL connections. When the upload bandwidth of the DSL line saturates, the download bandwidth can be choked to almost nothing, therefore you **must** limit BitTorrent upload speed to 90% or less of the available upload bandwidth when using a DSL line.

Answer (score 2):

It uses your bandwidth, so like all other online softwares, it slows down your internet browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it takes if you have no limits and there are a lot
/fast of peers.