# Should Loading torrents slow down ping?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ping

If one PC is downloading a torrent, should the ping on the other device take longer. I have read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/317411/does-torrenting-slow-down-internet-browsing) and I understand that it should take up bandwith, but ping does not really need any bandwidth, therefore I assume the speed of ping should not be impacted.

I have a wireless router with DHCP enabled that is connected to a modem. I get these interruptions when somebody else is using the Wi-Fi

Comment: Pings on the local network or over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

WiFi is using a shared medium (i.e. the electro-magnetic spectrum) for transportation of messages. That means that only one sender can send messages at each point of time. If WiFi is under high load a sender needs to wait for a free time slot (nobody else is sending). This can result in higher round-trip-times aka high ping.

One way to solve this, would be to create and use a second WiFi (e.g. using 2.4 GHz for torrenting ans 5 GHz for ping).

Comment: It also depends on the poster's router. Some newer routers can handle multiple devices in parallel.

Comment: Yes, some senders are capable to send messages to multiple devices concurrently and thus mitigate the problem. However, a client always has to wait for a free time slot to send its data - otherwise it would destroy the packets that are send concurrently.

Comment: Or Setting the torrent port number as the lowest priority service in the router qos is also an option. (If it has qos) probably the router state table is overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

What happens under torrenting depends entirely on the capabilities of the router.
Some routers chock on too many connections. If the torrenting software is set
to use too many connections for the router, new requests will need to wait.
The number of connections, as opposed to the bandwidth per connection, can play a difference in how the router performs

To improve your throughput, you should limit the number of connection for both
upload and download. You should sharply limit your upload bandwidth and
connections number.